# Faster NSArray lookup using NSDictionary storing indices as values

Tags: objective-c, ios, data-structures, nsarray, nsdictionary

Lets say I have a Student class as below:

```
class Student {
    NSNumber *id;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSString *firstName; 
}
```

Now when I get the records of all the students from a web service, I have an NSArray that stores records for all the students. At some point of time I need to look up the array to find a particular student's record based upon first name.

Assume I create a dictionary called studentsFirstNameDictionary.

So while adding objects to students array, I can do

```
Student objStudent = [[Student alloc] init];
objStudent.Id = someId;
objStudent.firstName = someName;
objStudent.lastName = someLastName;
[studentsDictionary setValue:iterationCounter forKey:objStudent.firstName];
[students addObject:objStudent];
```

I want to know if it is a good idea to create this dictionary to speed up the look up as below. Also please assume that in any case the array is required and for fast lookup I am creating other dictionaries too storing the last name and id as keys and indices as values like above:

```
-(Student*)getStudentByFirstName:(NSString *)firstName {
  int idxOfStudent = [ studentsDictionary valueForKey:firstName];
  return [students idxOfStudent];
}
```

Do you think this approach is performance wise better than having to iterate through the students array and compare the first name and return the matching student record?

I always need the students array because I need to populate a table view with that array. I am wondering if it is wise to create multiple dictionaries while populating the array so that I can look up a student record faster by fist name, last name or Id?

P.S.: For sake of simplicity, consider that all students have unique first name, last name and id so there will not be any issue while creating dictionaries storing first name, last name or ID as a value.

Comment: Why not just store a dictionary from the first name to the Student object itself?

Comment: How many students?  If there are many then why not store them in a sqlite database (possibly using Core Data)?

Comment: You can use NSOrderedSet which is a mixture of NSArray and NSSet, or NSHashTable which is a bit harder to use, but more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the array at all.

Create your Student objects:

```
Student objStudent = [[Student alloc] init];
objStudent.Id = someId;
objStudent.firstName = someName;
objStudent.lastName = someLastName;
[studentsDictionary setObject:student forKey:objStudent.firstName];
```

To look up a student by `firstName`:

```
Student * theStudent = [ studentsDictionary objectForKey:firstName ] ;
```

To get all Student objects from `studentsDictionary`, use

```
NSArray * allStudents = [ studentsDictionary allValues ] ;
```

This assumes you will only be finding students by their `firstName` attribute however.. @rickster's solution might be better in general

Comment: Actually, I'd say this approach still works even if you have multiple ways to look up `Student`s: just create multiple dictionaries mapping different attributes to the same set of `Student`s. Each `Student` only exists once, and the overhead for creating another dictionary isn't much. You will have to be careful when deleting them, though. (Oh, and I assumed in my answer that there's some reason for having an array to start with... obviously this isn't necessarily true -- drop the array if having them in dictionaries makes more sense!)

Comment: The only reason to use the array would be to preserve ordering of the objects. `-[NSDictionary allValues]` returns the objects in no particular order. An alternative would be to sort the array before display.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds more complicated than it needs to be. Generally in Cocoa, if you find yourself consulting a data structures textbook for this common a task, either you've missed something in the [Foundation docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) or you're [optimizing prematurely](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Given an array of `Student` objects, there are at least a couple of quick and easy ways to get the one with a unique attribute:

#### use a block test:

```
NSUInteger index = [studentArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj.firstName isEqualToString:desiredFirstName]) {
        *stop = YES;  // keeps us from returning multiple students with same name
        return YES;
    } else
        return NO;
}];
if (index != NSNotFound)
    Student *desiredStudent = [studentArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

#### use a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName LIKE %@", desiredFirstName];
NSArray *filteredArray = [studentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
Student *desiredStudent = [lastObject]; // only object if we assume firstNames are unique
```

Both of these assume your `Student` class has declared properties (or KVC-complient accessors) for those fields (that is, not just instance variables).

If you find yourself frequently accessing students by name, you might want to consider a dictionary mapping names to `Student` objects:

```
NSMutableDictionary *studentsByName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[students count]];
for (Student *student in students)
    [studentsByName setObject:student forKey:[student firstName]];
```

If you have a very large number of students and want to search them by various attributes, you might consider learning about Core Data.

Comment: Thanks rickster.
I know all this approaches and use them frequently. I wanted to know the cost of what I am doing. I wanted to know if it is any better than iterating through the array whenever a lookup is required.
First two approaches you suggested both iterates through the array so having large number of elements would be a performance hit. 

I am interested in knowing if the approach I mentioned is performance wise any better than using indexOfObjectPassingTest or filterArrayUsingPredicate?

Comment: The best answer to any performance question is to test it yourself. Make a whole lot of `Student`s, do a thousand lookups, and time it. Some general thoughts on performance, though...

Comment: For a single iteration through the array, `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` (or `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`, or any of the variants on either) should be pretty fast. For one thing, the internal enumeration it does is likely faster than any loop you'd write; and for another, it's only grabbing an index (or several). (Also, some of those variants can be made to run concurrently on multiple CPUs.) Also for a single iteration, `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is likely faster than your code, but slower than `indexOfObjectPasingTest:`, since it's creating a new array.

Comment: Neither search method is going to be efficient if you're doing it every time you look up a `Student`, though -- your intuition of doing some setup ahead of time is good. However, having a dictionary mapping names to array indexes is going to be slower than having a dictionary mapping names to actual `Student` objects because of the extra level of indirection. And on top of that, what happens to your dictionary lookup plan if you change the order of `Student`s in your array?